# Exception: DNS error: (line 30, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I'm attempting to use this spreadsheet:

```
 https://kennymcnett.com/domain-name-checker-in-google-sheets/
```

I obtained an API Key from RapidAPI.

However I am receiving the following error message:

```
 Exception: DNS error: https://domainr.p.mashape.com/v2/status?mashape-key=f23.....25c5&domain=undefined (line 30, file "Code")
```

Line 30 of the extension is:

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+domain);
```

All of the code in the extension:

```
// Works as of April 6, 2016

// domainr docs: http://domainr.build/docs/overview

// Get your free API key from https://market.mashape.com/domainr/domainr
// Create an application, get a key
// Put your key into the cell on the "Instructions" sheet


/* sample return JSON from domainr.p.mashape.com
* 
* https://domainr.p.mashape.com/v2/status?mashape-key=YOURKEYHERE&domain=testasfkljhsdf.com
* 
* Produces:
* 
* {"status":[{"domain":"testasfkljhsdf.com","zone":"com","status":"undelegated inactive","summary":"inactive"}]}
* 
*/

function domainLookup(domain) {
  if (domain == "") {
    return "N/A";
  }

  //Get the Key from cell A11 on the sheet named "Key"
  var key = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Instructions').getRange('key').getValue(); //range = named range of the cell with the API key in it

  //Submit to mashape
  var url = "https://domainr.p.mashape.com/v2/status?mashape-key=" + key + "&domain=";
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+domain);
  var out = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
  var answer = out.status[0].summary;

  //Interpret the answer
  if (answer == 'undelegated' || answer == 'inactive') {
    var finalAnswer = "Available";
  } else {
    var finalAnswer = "Nope";
  }

  //Logger.log(out);
  //Logger.log(finalAnswer);

  //Show the answer
  return finalAnswer;
}
```

These are the instructions in the spreadsheet:

```
For more detailed instructions and other information about this document, see the write-up:
http://kennymcnett.com/domain-name-checker-in-google-sheets/

Instructions

Step 1
Make a copy of this document into your own Google Drive. Then, don't change anything on this sheet except the API Key

Step 2
Get a domainr.com API key from mashape.com

Step 3
Paste your domainr API key from mashape.com below:
f236......................................b0725c5

Step 4
Go to the Domain Names sheet and have fun!

Bonus
If you want to see the script code, go to "Tools > Script editor..."For more detailed instructions and other information about this document, see the write-up:
http://kennymcnett.com/domain-name-checker-in-google-sheets/

Instructions

Step 1
Make a copy of this document into your own Google Drive. Then, don't change anything on this sheet except the API Key

Step 2
Get a domainr.com API key from mashape.com

Step 3
Paste your domainr API key from mashape.com below:
f236.........................................25c5

Step 4
Go to the Domain Names sheet and have fun!

Bonus
If you want to see the script code, go to "Tools > Script editor..."
```

Edit: Was able to solve this error by changing the URL to:

`domainr.p.rapidapi.com`

However after doing so I am now receiving a new error message:

`Exception: Request failed for domainr.p.rapidapi.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: {"message":"You are not subscribed to this API."} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 30).`

Things I have done to so far: 
 1. Verify that the API I am using is a free API. According to this URL the sub-domain I am using is for the free version of this api: 

`https://domainr.p.rapidapi.com (free or non-commercial use)`


`source: https://domainr.com/docs/api`

2. I verified that I don't have to input my credit card data to access free api's. According to this documentation, free api's don't require me to input credit card info to my RapidAPI account. 
   `

`

> FREE APIs
>
> RapidAPI has thousands of FREE APIs. As the name suggests, you can try
>   any of these APIs without providing credit card details. These APIs
>   are clearly marked as FREE.
>
> Required Third-Party API Key
>
> Occasionally you’ll need to acquire an API key or token from the
>   provider’s website.

`

`source: https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/api-pricing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Eric from Domainr, try using `domainr.p.rapidapi.com` as the hostname (not `mashape`) -- RapidAPI recently deprecated the `mashape` hostname for some reason.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm receiving this error: 
Exception: Request failed for https://domainr.p.rapidapi.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: {"message":"You are not subscribed to this API."} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 30).

My change to line 29: 
var url = "https://domainr.p.rapidapi.com/v2/status?mashape-key=" + key + "&domain=";

Comment: You'll need to contact RapidAPI support for assistance with this issue, because you are connecting to their service. The error says what you need to do: subscribe to the Domainr API with your RapidAPI account.

Comment: The  solution was to subscribe to the api pricing plan here: 
https://rapidapi.com/domainr/api/domainr/pricing

the documentation listed the api as "free", when it was in fact "freemium".

Answer (score 1):

This is Kenny, writer of the blog post you referenced. In case you're still having issues, I have updated the blog post to reflect several changes that will get this working for you. https://kennymcnett.com/domain-name-checker-in-google-sheets/